# SQL Server : GETDATE not returning today's date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Below is my query. Everything is working except for the `GETDATE` function in the `WHERE` clause. It won't return today's date if I put the date in there like this: 7/12/22. It is a `DATETIME` column in the backend. Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT 
    acsMFG.dbo.production_posting_trans.item_no,
    SUM(acsMFG.dbo.production_posting_trans.good_quantity) AS [Good Qty],
    SUM(acsMFG.dbo.production_posting_trans.scrap_quantity) AS [Scrap Qty],
    acsAUTOSYS.dbo.inventory_master.selling_price
FROM
    acsAUTOSYS.dbo.inventory_master
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    acsMFG.dbo.production_posting_trans ON acsMFG.dbo.production_posting_trans.item_no = acsAUTOSYS.dbo.inventory_master.item_no
                                        AND acsAUTOSYS.dbo.inventory_master.company_code = acsMFG.dbo.production_posting_trans.company_code
WHERE  
    acsMFG.dbo.production_posting_trans.company_code = '10'
    AND acsMFG.dbo.production_posting_trans.production_date = GETDATE()
    AND acsMFG.dbo.production_posting_trans.posting_type = 'MMQ'
        OR acsMFG.dbo.production_posting_trans.posting_type = 'IRS'
        OR acsMFG.dbo.production_posting_trans.posting_type = 'PME'
GROUP BY 
    acsMFG.dbo.production_posting_trans.item_no,
    acsAUTOSYS.dbo.inventory_master.selling_price
```

Comment: I really suggest getting in the habit of aliasing your objects and using those to clarify your columns. 4 part naming for columns makes your code very unwieldy and 3+ naming for columns is to be deprecated. Using aliases will make your code much more succinct and readable.

Comment: You are missing parentheses in your WHERE clause. But you should just use `IN` for those three or-ed conditions anyway

Comment: I suspect those `OR` clauses are not working as you expect either.

Comment: Also why are you using a `full outer join`? Your `WHERE` conditions will turn it into a `RIGHT JOIN` anyway

Comment: I would like to use aliases but I don't know how. I am just hearing about them today actually. I'm not very good with SQL but I'm trying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, when you say `SELECT GETDATE();` what do you see? There is a time component there too, so if the data in the table is `2022-07-12 15:12` and you run the query at `2022-07-12 15:13`, that's not a match.

If you want data from today, you need a range query:

```
WHERE col >= CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
  AND col <  DATEADD(DAY, 1, CONVERT(date, GETDATE()));
```

It is cleaner to use variables, e.g.

```
DECLARE @today date = GETDATE();
DECLARE @tomorrow date = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @today);

...
WHERE col >= @today
  AND col <  @tomorrow;
```

Don't get tempted into doing this:

```
WHERE CONVERT(date, col) = CONVERT(date, GETDATE());
```

It will work, but [it's not fantastic](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/34047/1186).

For the actual problem with OR logic, you have:

```
  ... date clauses with AND ...
  AND acsMFG.dbo.production_posting_trans.posting_type='MMQ' 
  Or acsMFG.dbo.production_posting_trans.posting_type ='IRS' 
  Or acsMFG.dbo.production_posting_trans.posting_type ='PME'
```

I think you want:

```
  AND 
  (
    acsMFG.dbo.production_posting_trans.posting_type='MMQ' 
    Or acsMFG.dbo.production_posting_trans.posting_type ='IRS' 
    Or acsMFG.dbo.production_posting_trans.posting_type ='PME'
  )
```

As for aliases:

```
FROM
  acsAUTOSYS.dbo.inventory_master AS im
FULL OUTER JOIN 
  acsMFG.dbo.production_posting_trans AS ppt
```

Now all your references can be:

```
  AND 
  (
    ppt.posting_type='MMQ' 
    ppt.posting_type ='IRS' 
    Or ppt.posting_type ='PME'
  )
  GROUP BY 
    ppt.item_no, im.selling_price;
```

Or better:

```
  AND 
  (
    ppt.posting_type IN ('MMQ', 'IRS', 'PME')
  )
  GROUP BY 
    ppt.item_no, im.selling_price;
```

...so much more readable.

Comment: I put the code in like this but I'm still getting data for all of time.

```
WHERE acsMFG.dbo.production_posting_trans.company_code='10' AND acsMFG.dbo.production_posting_trans.production_date >= CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
  AND acsMFG.dbo.production_posting_trans.production_date <  DATEADD(DAY, 1, CONVERT(date, GETDATE())) AND acsMFG.dbo.production_posting_trans.posting_type='MMQ' Or acsMFG.dbo.production_posting_trans.posting_type ='IRS' Or acsMFG.dbo.production_posting_trans.posting_type ='PME'
```

Comment: Oh, I see. As mentioned in the comments, you need parens around your OR conditions to make it clear what you want. "I want a burger and fries or onion rings." Does that mean "I want a burger AND (fries or onion rings)" or does it mean "I want (a burger and fries) OR (onion rings)"? These have different meanings. If you say "in this date range AND this other thing OR yet another thing" you will get rows that match "yet another thing" without having to match date range or this other thing.

Comment: Thank you! I read too quickly through your comment about the OR conditions. Things look like they are working how I want them to now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Since GETDATE() returns the time too, you will never match. You need something like:

```
CAST(acsMFG.dbo.production_posting_trans.production_date AS Date) 
         = CAST(GETDATE() AS Date)
```

Comment: But `production_date` is datetime according to the OP, so you will still never match unless there is data exactly at midnight.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I missed that part, thanks.